# How to place element both at the bottom of the page and at the center of its div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9 text-center">
      <button>
        Bottom
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x244qg6a/

Now I want to place the second row at the bottom of the page.

If I just do the following

```
.push-to-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row push-to-bottom">
    <div class="col-xs-9 text-center">
      <button>
        Bottom
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it will ignore the `text-center` class then (https://jsfiddle.net/nnkb7e2r/).

What can I do to achieve such behavior?

Comment: check my answer below. be sure to change the `.row.push-to-bottom {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px;}` to `0` because  that is causing some problems in alignment

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
width: 100%;
```

to

```
.push-to-bottom
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnkb7e2r/2/)

Comment: Well, it works strange on my page. It enlarges the page so it has additional empty horizontal space

Comment: Any chance of a link ?

Comment: I can't reproduce it on JSFiddle unfortunately

Comment: Try adding an outline to see where the extra space is coming from and then maybe reduce the width to 90 or 80%

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Flexbox` on container element with `flex-direction: column` and `height: 100vh` so it takes full window height. Then you can set `margin-top: auto` on second row and that will push that row to bottom of container. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nnkb7e2r/1/)

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.push-to-bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the `.push-to-bottom` to be on the bottom side of the `.container` , so you need to set `position:relative` to `.container` and also a height, because by using `position:absolute` , the height of the `.container` remains only equal to the `height` of the `.row`  in this example i've set a height of `100vh` which is the viewport height.

or you could simply leave it as it is ( ignore the first line in my CSS ) and it will stay relative to the document

and to center the `push-to-bottom` div use :`left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto`

ALSO be sure to put `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `0` at `.row.push-to-bottom` because in bootstrap `.row` has `margin-left:-15px;` and `margin-right:-15px;`

also made some more changes in CSS so it looks nicely, but you can ignore them

let me know if it helps

```css
.container {
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid black;
  
}
.push-to-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;

  border:2px solid blue;
   }
.push-to-bottom .col-xs-9 {
  width:100%;
}
.row .col-xs-3 { 
text-align:right
}
.push-to-bottom.row { 
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/latest/journal/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row push-to-bottom">
    <div class="col-xs-9 text-center">
      <button>
        Bottom
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define width for outer div whose position is absolute and height for container.

```
.container{
position:relative;
height:100vh;
}
.push-to-bottom{
width:100%;
}
```